# How to change the color of unselected tab bar items in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

Im trying to change the color of the unselected images in the tab bar, by default they are changed to gray, even if the image is another color.

I already search this, but the answers are only for iOS 6 or below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This drove me mad just recently so I wrote my own class to handle it that works with every version of iOS I've tried it on ;)  Its really easy to extend to do whatever you want it to do too!

GozTabBar.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "GozTabBarItem.h"

@protocol GozTabBarDelegate;

@interface GozTabBar : UIView
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer* pTapGestureRecognizer;

}

@property                                   UIColor*                    backgroundColour;
@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic)    id < GozTabBarDelegate >    delegate;
@end

@protocol GozTabBarDelegate < NSObject >

- (int)             getNumberOfTabBarItemsForTabBar: (GozTabBar*) pTabBar;
- (GozTabBarItem*)  getTabBarItemsAtIndex: (int) index ForTabBar: (GozTabBar*) pTabBar;
- (void)            selectedItemAtIndex: (int) index ForTabBar: (GozTabBar*) pTabBar;
- (int)             getSelectedItemIndexForTabBar: (GozTabBar*) pTabBar;
@end
```

GozTabBar.m

```
#import "GozTabBar.h"
#import "GozTabBarItem.h"

@implementation GozTabBar

@synthesize backgroundColour;
@synthesize delegate;

const int leftEdgeInset         = 8;
const int rightEdgeInset        = 8;

const int topEdgeInset          = 8;
const int bottomEdgeInset       = 8;

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        pTapGestureRecognizer   = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action: @selector( onTap: )];
        [self addGestureRecognizer: pTapGestureRecognizer];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self)
    {
        pTapGestureRecognizer   = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action: @selector( onTap: )];
        [self addGestureRecognizer: pTapGestureRecognizer];
    }
    return  self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        pTapGestureRecognizer   = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action: @selector( onTap: )];
        [self addGestureRecognizer: pTapGestureRecognizer];
    }
    return self;
}

// Recognise a tap on the item (If it is on an item).
- (void)onTap: (UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    const int leftRightEdgeInset    = leftEdgeInset + rightEdgeInset;
    const int topBottomEdgeInset    = topEdgeInset + bottomEdgeInset;

    int numItems        = 0;
    if ( [self.delegate respondsToSelector: @selector( getNumberOfTabBarItemsForTabBar: )] )
    {
        numItems    = [self.delegate getNumberOfTabBarItemsForTabBar: self];
    }
    if ( numItems > 0 )
    {
        int widthLessInset  = (self.frame.size.width - leftRightEdgeInset);
        int itemWidth       = widthLessInset / numItems;

        int heightLessInset = self.frame.size.height - topBottomEdgeInset;
        int itemHeight      = heightLessInset;

        CGPoint tapPoint    = [gestureRecognizer locationInView: self];

        // Draw the custom items.
        for( int i = 0; i < numItems; i++ )
        {
            CGRect tabBarItemRect   = CGRectMake( leftEdgeInset + (itemWidth * i), 0, itemWidth, itemHeight );
            if ( CGRectContainsPoint( tabBarItemRect, tapPoint ) )
            {
                if ( [self.delegate respondsToSelector: @selector(selectedItemAtIndex:ForTabBar:)] )
                {
                    [self.delegate selectedItemAtIndex: i ForTabBar: self];
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    const int leftRightEdgeInset    = leftEdgeInset + rightEdgeInset;
    const int topBottomEdgeInset    = topEdgeInset + bottomEdgeInset;

    CGContextRef ctx    = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Fill the background in the relevant colour.
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor( ctx, backgroundColour.CGColor );
    CGContextFillRect( ctx, rect );

    int numItems        = 0;
    if ( [self.delegate respondsToSelector: @selector( getNumberOfTabBarItemsForTabBar: )] )
    {
        numItems    = [self.delegate getNumberOfTabBarItemsForTabBar: self];
    }
    if ( numItems > 0 )
    {
        int widthLessInset  = (rect.size.width - leftRightEdgeInset);
        int itemWidth       = widthLessInset / numItems;

        int heightLessInset = rect.size.height - topBottomEdgeInset;
        int itemHeight      = heightLessInset;

        int selectedIndex   = 0;
        if ( [self.delegate respondsToSelector: @selector(getSelectedItemIndexForTabBar:)] )
        {
            selectedIndex   = [self.delegate getSelectedItemIndexForTabBar: self];
        }


        // Draw the custom items.
        for( int i = 0; i < numItems; i++ )
        {
            //GozTabBarItem*    pItem   = [self.items objectAtIndex: i];
            GozTabBarItem*  pItem   = nil;
            if ( [self.delegate respondsToSelector: @selector(getTabBarItemsAtIndex:ForTabBar:)] )
            {
                pItem   = [self.delegate getTabBarItemsAtIndex: i ForTabBar: self];
            }
            if ( pItem != nil )
            {
                CGRect  tabBarItemRect      = CGRectMake( leftEdgeInset + (itemWidth * i), topEdgeInset, itemWidth, itemHeight );
                CGPoint tabBarItemCenter    = CGPointMake( tabBarItemRect.origin.x + (tabBarItemRect.size.width / 2), tabBarItemRect.origin.y + (tabBarItemRect.size.height / 2) );

                UIImage* pDrawImage = nil;
                if ( i == selectedIndex )
                {
                    pDrawImage = pItem.selectedImage;
                }
                else
                {
                    pDrawImage = pItem.unSelectedImage;
                }

                CGRect drawRect = CGRectMake( tabBarItemCenter.x - (pDrawImage.size.width / 2), tabBarItemCenter.y - (pDrawImage.size.height / 2), pDrawImage.size.width, pDrawImage.size.height );
                [pDrawImage drawInRect: drawRect];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

GozTabBarItem.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface GozTabBarItem : NSObject
{
}

@property UIImage*  selectedImage;
@property UIImage*  unSelectedImage;

- (id) initWithSelectedImage: (UIImage*) selectedImage andUnselectedImage: (UIImage*) unSelectedImage;

@end
```

GozTabBarItem.m

```
#import "GozTabBarItem.h"

@implementation GozTabBarItem

@synthesize selectedImage;
@synthesize unSelectedImage;

- (id) initWithSelectedImage: (UIImage*) selectedImg andUnselectedImage: (UIImage*) unSelectedImg
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        self.selectedImage      = selectedImg;
        self.unSelectedImage    = unSelectedImg;
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Hope that helps.