# Set Image on UITabBar Controller

Tags: ios, xcode

I have developed tabbar base application which have 5 tabs and i am trying to set images on each tabs. so I've used inbuid functionalities which provide by xcode for setting images but I'm not getting exact results which I want.

here is my TabBar Controller
[image]

in this case I am getting images in Grey colors but my actual images are not grey its a colored images. so please any one have solution to solve this issues. I want to set image as reties which I have.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change inactive icon/text color on tab bar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22767098/how-to-change-inactive-icon-text-color-on-tab-bar)

Answer (score 0):

Begin from iOS 7, you can choose to treat any of the images in your app as a template—or stencil—image. When you elect to treat an image as a template, the system ignores the image’s color information and creates an image stencil based on the alpha values in the image. `UIImage` has a new property named `renderingMode` The default rendering mode is `UIImageRenderingModeAutomatic`. From my experience it usually means template like image so when you init your image you need

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someimage"];
UIImage *thisoneshouldbeused = [image imageWithRenderingMode: UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]
```

See Template Images in UIKit User Interface Catalog for more information

Answer (score 0):

[@Inertiatic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21597313/1298400) has a great answer, use `-imageWithRenderingMode:`.

```
NSArray *images = @[@"[FIRST IMAGE]", @"[SECOND IMAGE]", …];
NSArray *selectedImages = @[@"[FIRST SELECTED IMAGE]", @"[SECOND SELECTED IMAGE]", …];

UITabBarController *tabBarController = (id)self.window.rootViewController;

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < tabBarController.tabBar.items.count; ++i) {
    UITabBarItem *item in tabBarController.tabBar.items[i];

    item.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:images[i]] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    item.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:selectedImages[i]] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
}
```