# Tab bar item icons appear darker

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem, xcode-storyboard

When setting the icons for the tab bar items it seems that the icons are appearing darker for some reason. Examples below

**Tab bar in app**

[image]

**What it should be like from designs**

[image]

As you can see in the second example the colours are softer and lighter compared to the ones above i can't seem to figure out why because even in my image.xcassets the icons look like the ones in the design and in my setting in the identity inspector shown below there doesn't seem to be any settings for tints.

**Storyboard**

[image]

Comment: iOS uses the image you provide as a template, ignoring the color, and applying a default for the unselected ones, and the tint for the selected item. You should check this answer if you don't want this behaviour: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21596515/to-change-the-color-of-unselected-uitabbar-icon-in-ios-7

Comment: So you want to make UITabBar icons to RGB colors?